# Image Gets Uploaded While env is set to Amazon S3 but shows YAML error when env set to local

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, spree, rails-activestorage

YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /app/config/storage.yml.
Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces.
Tabs are not allowed. Error: (): did not find expected tag URI while parsing a tag at line 16 column 11

This is occurring while uploading images from Spree Commerce Admin Panel .

Comment: As its a syntax error, please do add your storage.yml file here, so that we can help more.

Comment: I have checked my Storage.yml file and the indentation is correct and has checked over other YAML parsers and I... Still Getting the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!!

In Storage.yml write the local service: as a `disk` instead of a `Disk`.

Also Add `require 'yaml'` in the environment.rb file

Along With adding A YAML gem or upgrading to the latest YAML gem Version Available. [Check Here](https://rubygems.org/gems/yaml/versions/0.2.0)